# Django Grappelli installed but not being applied

Tags: django, django-grappelli

I've gone through the installation, here:

http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation

But I can't get it to work. Looking at the troubleshooting guide,

http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting

it says that I need to check that the static files are being served correctly. How can I do that?

Comment: "does not work" ? What is that supposed to mean ?

Comment: It still shows the default interface.

Comment: Maybe you installed wrong ? paste settings.py and urls.py, also ensure that you are using `manage.py runserver` for the time of this question.

Comment: strictly use the correct order for the app in  settings.py and urls in urls.py